# Changing pronoun while referring to the same person

Tags: creative-writing, lyrics

> He sneaked into the wilderness
>
> His feet close to his hand
>
> Ready to pounce
>
> Ready to kill
>
> He was like a beast

> I am like a lion
>
> King of the jungle
>
> I am like a lion
>
> King of the jungle
>
> A wild beast without conscience

Can we do this? And what do you call the act of referring to oneself in the third person? Is this a widely used technique?

Comment: Poetry or lyrics for a song? This reads like poetry, but the tag says lyrics. It's switching from third person to first person, but there may be an actual term (IDK)

Comment: I can see the first section being sung as verse by a single singer and the second, as refrain sung by the whole band... and conceptually as a kind of dialog or statement from "him".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were reading this I would probably assume that this was referring to two different people, unless three was some indication otherwise. "He" and "I" could be two different people, or the same person viewed first from the outside, and then from the inside.

Referring to oneself in the third person is a recognized technique, but if it has a nice simple name, I don't know what it is.

In any case one should find a way to clue the reader in, or risk a confused reader. Of course in some cases ambiguity is the point, or part of the point.